# when will JSF @PostConstruct be called again?

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I'm making an application with spring+primefaces

I created a init function in managed bean to load some useful data (the bean is `@ViewScope`)

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        log.debug("initing....");
        currentUser = UserUtil.getCurrentUser(this.userManager);
        loadData();
    }
```

later in view I have some tags to hide columns like this:

```
<p:column rendered="#{dataManagedBean.currentUser.manager}"> // to test if the current user is a manager role
...
...
</p:column>
```

the problem is when I login with a normal user, then even logout and login with manager user, the column I want to show is not showing, because the `init()` method is not calling again therefore the "currentUser" remains  the oldone (normal suer)

**UPDATE**

the problem maybe I mixed Spring DI and JSF managed beans, there is more detail

- in javabean layer: I used `@Entity` annotation for hibernate
- in dao layer: I use `@Repository("DataDao")` to inject the daos (from
  spring)
- in manager layer: I use use many spring annotations to inject like
  `@Service("DataManager")` `@Authowire` `@Qualifier` etc
- in view layer,  since I have been using spring to inject, thats why I
  use  `@Component("DataManagedBean")` and `@ViewScope`

I have been 2 weeks with the application, and everything worked as expected. untill I found today @PostConstruct is actually never call again, the view is never destroy :S  (or it's intented to work like this, a singleton...)

Can someone kindly explain me where I did wrong?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think as long as you stay in the same view, you're going to initialize it only once. Are you staying at the same page?

Comment: No, when user click "log out" it redirected to logout page then login page. i have changed to sessionScope and still happens the same

Comment: May be you have some attributes which use #{dataManagedBean.xxx} at your template. Are you use like that?

Comment: Hmm I m not sure what do you mean sorry :/

Comment: @Kossel just staring at your snippet, I can't tell what's wrong, seems ok to me. Maybe you could try creating a little project and uploading it to some github (I know, it's a lot of work)

Comment: There's hardly ever a good reason to back a page with an `@SessionScoped` bean. Always pick between the `@RequestScoped` and `@ViewScoped`. Your issue is between the wrong bean scope you have chosen and the render condition on that column

Comment: @kolossus: Nope. His issue is that he's using Spring instead of JSF or CDI to manage beans.

Comment: @BalusC as long as the bean he is using is JSF managed using Spring with JSF doesn't have to be a problem. But the change is that his bean is spring managed (and with luck even his `@ViewScope` is rendered useless and he is using a singleton instead).

Comment: @M.Deinum: Exactly. OP incorrectly assumed that bean scope annotations are exchangable across various bean management frameworks. OP wanted to use the JSF (or CDI; package isn't visible in his current and previous questions) view scope annotation, but used Spring instead of JSF (or CDI) to manage the bean.

Comment: @BalusC I have updated the question regarding what you said. any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an intensive reading about JSF scopes, specially thanks to @M. Deinum's comments and Mr @BalusC's [excelent article](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) explaining about the JSF communication topic. I understand why the user object survived event after logout/relogin.

My mistake is combining Spring DI (by using `@Component` annotation) and JSF annotation (by using `@ViewScoped`), then the `@ViewScoped` annotation is ignored and default spring scope is used, which is by default a singleton...